# Sending a password over an unencrypted connection

Tags: encryption, passwords

I'm working on a game launcher, that has a C# frontend and PHP backend for authentication, and I need to send the password from the launcher to the backend over an unencrypted connection. Is there any way to do it safely? (Passwords are stores as blowfish hashes in the database beginning with $2y...)

Answer (score 4):

`Establishing an SSL` connection is one of the most commonly-used methods to transfer sensitive information like passwords. For that, at least you must provide your server/backend with a key pair (certificate). It does not have to be signed by veriSign if your app itself would work towards it and not a browser.

Note that: What you really after is 'confidentiality'. It means no one except you and your intended party can read the message content. That comes with 'proper usage of encryption mechanisms' in most cases. You also want to be secure against attacks such as [Man in the Middle Attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Very often developers just program something that works and think about security later; but there is an unquestionable benefit if you can think of it ahead of time.

Edit: In case you only need to send a password securely and that's all, then @rich.okelly's answer would be the answer. Since you can hardcode the server's trusted public key on the app, and just encrypt that password by the client. But if you want to have secure connection for more/all of your sessions, you might want to consider going for the SSL solution.

Answer (score 2):

In all cases, your requirement is this:

Starting with an insecure, unencrypted means of transferring data, how do I end up with a secure, encrypted means of transferring data for at least long enough to send a password?

- The Internet always starts out as an insecure and unencrypted!

There are many ways, and [rolling your own](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) is the worst of them.  Options include but are not limited to:

- Use a C# library like [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)

  - To create a TLS 1.2 session using an AEAD cipher suite
  - To use asymmetric ciphers like RSA, ECDSA, or DSA (with a key >=2048 bits) to encrypt the password
- Use VPN software like [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html)
- Call [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/)

  - To create a TLS 1.2 session using an AEAD cipher suite
  - To use asymmetric ciphers like RSA, ECDSA, or DSA (with a key >=2048 bits) to encrypt the password
- Call [GPG](https://gnupg.org/) to encrypt the password with your public key

In all cases, you'd have to change both your back end and your front end in some way, either directly, or adding another layer between them (VPN).

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, the best thing to do (assuming that the connection MUST be insecure), would be to encrypt the password before sending it and decrypt on the backend - effectively rolling your own message level encryption.

You'd need an asymmetric encryption mechanism for this to be feasible - public/private key is probably the easiest way to go for this.